# IBM MobileFirst Foundation v8 "Access Disabled" gives 500 error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

After setting "Access Disabled" on MFF Console for an app, the app is supposed to get 403 `"APPLICATION_DISABLED"` when trying to connect to the server via `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(),` but the app gets 500 `"API_INVOCATION_FAILURE"`, as the following screen capture:

[image]

Unfortunately, I could not find any previous cases of this error here or in other technical forum. What would cause MFF server returning 500 `API_INVOCATION_FAILURE error` from calling `obtainAccessToken()` API (even without calling any adapter procedure)?

Comment: Is this happening in native iOS apps or Cordova iOS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and this works for me.
I believe this may be related to a recent requirement by Apple to enable the "Keychain sharing" capability in Xcode 8 (otherwise requests will fail, and obtainAccessToken is basically a request).

Try enabling Keychain sharing and see if this is now resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Even though the overall architecture of the use of Mobile Foundation v8 in the environment is a bit weird, the issue has been resolved after applying ifix, leaving a question on what the root cause of the issue was yet..